# Migrating Published Artifacts in Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to migrate Published build artifacts from one project to another in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's now possible for now.

Artifact needs to be associated with a specific build, which cannot be created/imported, it needs to be triggered for a build definition.

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0